# Making Photoshop-like drop shadows in a game

Tags: c++, shader

I'm making a game where the game's size varies, so I want to make my own shadows. The api i'm using can fill rectangles, make ellipses, horizontal lines etc. And supports rgba. Given this, how could I make a drop shadow? I tried making a black to white gradient and setting the alpha to 20%, but it didnt look very good... I'm not sure how they are done. Thanks

Comment: I'm perticularly having trouble with edge blurring

Comment: What trouble with edge blurring?? Box blurs are simple compared to gaussian ones. And cheapier too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. copy the object,
2. move it in the opposite direction of the light source and use its distance as a weight,
3. turn it totally black,
4. blur it using the light source's distance as a weight, too,
5. put it behind the object,
6. lower the alpha if you want.
7. ?????
8. profit.

Comment: And use a multiplying blend mode, if you have the choice.

Comment: multiplying is a photoshop thing that is not easy to implement, in fact it can be very expensive CPU-wise if badly implemented since you have to deal with pixel calculation.

Comment: @Camilo: A lot of APIs that do multiply blending (such as Cairo and OpenGL) push it to the graphics card whenever possible, and implementations tend to be quite fast.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking it the brain-dead way :) But those APIs also must have some useful shadow effect or at least make it trivial to implement, right?